# PHP session doesn't pass variable

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to pass variables from one page to another, but although I have checked for multiple errors, I just can't find the reason why the second page (`page1.php`,`page.2.php` or `page3.php`, depending on variable) does not receive the variable from the first page (`intro.php`).

Could anyone help me?

This is `intro.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

$pageorder = array("page1", "page2", "page3", "page4");
shuffle($pageorder);

$_SESSION['intro']= $pageorder[0];
$_SESSION['echo ($pageorder[0])']= $pageorder[1];
$_SESSION['echo ($pageorder[1])']= $pageorder[2];
$_SESSION['echo ($pageorder[2])']= $pageorder[3];

?>
```

and below html which determines the next page (which works fine):

```
<input type=hidden name="nextURL" value="<?php echo($pageorder[0])?>.php">
```

This is `page1.php`, in case `page1.php` was selected to be first (`page2.php`, etc. look similar):

```
<?php
session_start();

$page1 = $_SESSION['page1']; 
?>
```

and below the html again which determines the next page:

```
<input type=hidden name="nextURL" value="<?php echo ($page1) ?>.php">
```

Somehow it just doesn't receive anything, so $page1 is empty.

Does anybody see where the problem lies?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You cannot echo inside the identifier of the session array.

Comment: ^^ Look at the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);` and you'll see what went wrong in setting those values.

Comment: It doesn't work with $_SESSION['$pageorder[0]'] either...

Comment: `<input type=hidden` **Is that a big enough clue**

Comment: `$_SESSION['echo ($pageorder[0])']= $pageorder[1];` BAD `$_SESSION[$pageorder[0]]= $pageorder[1];` GOOD

Comment: Close as a Garden Variety Typo

Comment: Thanks so much, RiggsFolly! That was the solution.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the session correctly in the first script

```
<?php
session_start();

$pageorder = array("page1", "page2", "page3", "page4");
shuffle($pageorder);

$_SESSION['intro']= $pageorder[0];
$_SESSION[$pageorder[0]]= $pageorder[1];
$_SESSION[$pageorder[1]]= $pageorder[2];
$_SESSION[$pageorder[2]]= $pageorder[3];

?>
```

And the place where you are putting the data to see the result, is hidden, so remove the hidden attribute and with luck all will be well

```
<input type=hidden name="nextURL" value="<?php echo ($page1) ?>.php">
```

Change to

```
<input name="nextURL" value="<?php echo ($page1) ?>.php">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an array, just put that into your session array:

```
$_SESSION['page'] = $pageorder;
```

If the intro must be called intro, you could just do this as well:

```
$_SESSION['page'] = $item;
$_SESSION['intro'] = $item[0];
unset($_SESSION['page']['0']) //optional;
```

Then you have $_SESSION['intro'], $_SESSION['page'][1]..[3]